# Galois group of a quintic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

What is the Galois group of $x^5-4x+12$? I'm able to show it has to be either the Frobenius $F_{20}$ group, or the dihedral group $D_{10}$. Is there a less computationally heavy way to determine? What info does the discriminant tell me?

Comment: Are you sure? Reducing modulo $7$ or $13$ I find a product of a $2$-cycle and a $3$-cycle in the Galois group.

Comment: Less computationally heavy than what?

Comment: still up at the moment...T_T

Comment: The discriminant tells you whether the Galois group is a subgroup of the alternating group, which suffices to distinguish $D_{10}$ (yes) and $F_{20}$ (no).

Comment: It is $S_5$ according to Magma.

Comment: Hi. what is Magma?

Comment: Magma is computer algebra system specializing in group theory, number theory and algebraic number theory. Unlike GAP and Sage, it is not free, but it has a free online calculator http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ which can be used to do calculations like this. You just type in P<x> := PolynomialRing(Rationals());
Order(GaloisGroup(x^5 -4*x + 12)); and get the answer 120.

Comment: By the way, I am not suggesting that you should be using a computer to help you with exercises! But it can be useful for checking answers.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are working over the rationals.

Reducing modulo various primes $p$ ([see the beginning of Section 2 here](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/paper/gov.pdf)) one finds permutations of the following form (barring mistakes) in the Galois group:
\begin{matrix}
p &|& \text{cycle structure}\\\hline
7 &|& 2, 3\\
11 &|& 5\\
\end{matrix}
So the group has order at least $\operatorname{lcm}(2, 3, 5) = 30$, but there are *odd* permutations in it, so the group appears to be $S_{5}$.

Many thanks to **Peter Taylor** for spotting a mistake.

Comment: There is a mistake: $x^5 -4x + 12 = (x^2+6x+7)(x^3+7x^2+3x+11) \pmod {13}$

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thanks, must have misread the output, will fix ASAP.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, yes indeed, I had misread the output. Silly me.